# How to implement react-date-range picker with webpack module bundler?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm struggling to implement react date range picker with webpack module bundler. I've followed one of the npm react components for date range picker (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-range). If I try to implement with webpack I've got one error. That is, "Uncaught TypeError: type.toUpperCase is not a function". Please check my below code what i have tried so for,

```
var React  = require('react');
var DateRange = require('react-date-range');

var Calendarcomponent = React.createClass({
  handleSelect:function(range){
    console.log(range);
  },
  render:function(){
      return (
        <div>
          <DateRange
            onInit={this.handleSelect}
            onchange={this.handleSelect}
          />
        </div>
      )
  }
});

module.exports = Calendarcomponent;
```

Comment: did you install pkg moment ?

Comment: no @DhavalPatel. How to install that package?

Comment: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Hi @DhavalPatel. I've installed moment pkg. But still i'm getting same problem..

Comment: let me try to do it from my side

Comment: Okay thanks @DhavalPatel

Comment: Shouldn't need to install moment. It's a dependency of react-date-range already. https://github.com/Adphorus/react-date-range/blob/master/package.json#L30 I think the problem is that DateRange is not the default export of the package. You need to use `var DateRange = require('react-date-range').DateRange`

Comment: @azium:Perfect yes that's the reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateRange` is not the default export from the react-date-range package.

In the example, note the destructured syntax during the import:

```
import { DateRange } from 'react-date-range'
```

You would rewrite this in ES5 ala:

```
var DateRange = require('react-date-range').DateRange
```

Comment: Thanks @azium. How to display only one calendar?

Comment: Try `var Calendar = require('date-range-picker').Calendar`.

Comment: Hi @azium. How to get start and end date value when i click an external button?

Comment: @Sathya maybe you should make a new question for that, providing your updated code

Comment: Hi @azium. I have made a new question for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525835/how-to-get-start-and-end-date-value-in-reacte-date-range-picker

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the `react-date-range` as mentioned below

```
var DateRange = require('react-date-range').DateRange;
```